# How to know if an aircraft is climbing or descending?

Tags: aircraft-performance

As a ground observer, how can you tell if an aircraft is climbing or descending?

Comment: Do you have an ADS-B receiver? :)

Comment: Know the flight patterns of your area airports. Also, some aerobatics pilots and student pilots doing training are really easy to just listen to tell (Engine goes to idle: Descending. Engine roaring: Ascending).

Comment: @SMSvonderTann That will often be true, especially in cases of large power changes. However, in a recip with a fixed-pitch prop, a climb with no change in power (and attendant drop in airspeed) will result in a decrease in engine RPM and may appear to the ground observer to be a power reduction. By the same token, a descent (and attendant increase in airspeed) will result in an engine RPM increase and the appearance of a power increase.

Comment: It it is an airliner, get yourself the [flightradar app]/(http://www.flightradar24.com/apps)! The free version has a point feature that allows you to know climb rate, speed, model type, tail number, where it goes and where it comes from!

Comment: @SMSvonderTann Note the pitch change is subject to the speed of sound.  If the plane isn't right next to you there will be a noticeable lag between what you see the plane do and what you hear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listen. Climbing aircraft need more thrust, so the noise they produce is related to their vertical speed. Since most excess performance is available at low speed, a slowly flying aircraft producing a lot of noise will most likely be climbing. Once you gain a little experience, the pitch of the engine and propeller sound of piston-engined aircraft will be a very good indicator of their thrust setting.

This doesn't work for gliders. Here you need to wait to be sure if they are climbing or descending. Only when you see that the glider flies with speed brakes extended you can be sure instantly that it is descending.

Comment: I would argue the Doppler effect makes observing changes in pitch or volume unreliable when considering climbing or descending.

Comment: @RonBeyer: With the slow speed of propeller aircraft the Doppler effect is weak, especially if the aircraft is flying overhead. And this is the position where vertical speed is especially hard to judge from the ground.

Comment: Even so, its still difficult to determine relative power for pitch (climbing/descending/cruising) unless you hear the change in power as well. I'd say that yes, you can use it to observe rapid changes, but living near an airport usually an aircraft starts its descent long before you can hear it.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Don't forget the speed of sound: The change in engine pitch reaches your ear with a delay of one second for every 1000 feet of distance. When you see that the airplane begins to descend, you will hear the change in pitch several seconds later. If you know the type of aircraft well, you are very well able to judge its power setting by listening.

Comment: The listening option will often be true, but recips with fixed pitch props will not necessarily follow this rule of thumb, especially from the perspective of the uninitiated. The frequency of prop noise, a function of RPM whether driving or driven, will have no correlation to vertical speed.